# Installation SQL Server 2012 - “Ready to Install” page missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to create config file, so I could install sql server from cmd. I need basic server installation so I've downloaded SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU

I need to go through whole installation process til page "Ready to Install", where should be link to config file I need. BUT, there is no such thing in my installation setup window.

On microsoft webpage there is: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC505108.png

Although, the screen from MS is sql-server 2008.. How to get config file from installation sql-server-2012?

Here's my screen: 
[image]

Comment: The very last step before install should have the path to the configuration file. You have to continue through the wizard until that point.

Comment: There is no such way. Look at my screen. I've tried two times, and two times I've installed sql server :/

After Database Engine Configuration it starts install process. Maybe express edition is the issue ?

Comment: I will ask different way: 
When I install sql server from wizard, is there ConfigurationFile created anyway? I've installed sql server EXPRESS from begin to the end, and cannot find any configuration file on my desktop :/

Comment: I took a look -- yes, there is. If you go into the install location, do a search for `ConfigurationFile.ini`.

Comment: I did, actually I have a path to the ConfigurationFile.ini in log when installation ends. There is dir, but no ConfigurationFile.ini... I search my whole C: for ConfigurationFile.ini - no such a file (I have ConfigurationFile.ini for uninstall action... but no for install)

Comment: I have them for both, so I'm not sure what's up with your system. In any event, if you're having trouble with this, you're probably further ahead to start from a blank file and use the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) to build one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution...

When you have SQL Server 2012 EXPRESS edition, and you want to get ConfigurationFile.ini from your installation process, you have to:

1) Run downloaded exe, which will unpack your setup.exe to C:/231231231231...sth

2) Cancel installation. Go to that dir via cmd.

3) In cmd run: 
**setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /UIMODE=Normal**

Express edition is run in AutoAdvance which skips "Ready to install" and ConfigurationFile in general.. not sure why.

Comment: These steps still skipped the config file portion :(